# Does ActiveRecord handle looking up `enum`s by value when constructing the SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, enums

I have an [ActiveRecord enum](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) defined on my model as follows:

```rb
class ApiKey < ApplicationRecord
  enum api_version: { v1: -1, v2: 0, v3: 1 }
end
```

When I try to query by an enum's name, I noticed that ActiveRecord is not constructing the query correctly. 
e.g.

```rb
> ApiKey.where(owner_type: 'User', api_version: 'v3').to_sql
=> "SELECT \"api_keys\".* FROM \"api_keys\" WHERE \"api_keys\".\"owner_type\" = 'User' AND \"api_keys\".\"api_version\" = 0"
```

I specified `v3` so **I'd expect the resulting query to correctly look up it's raw enum value as `1`, but instead it's using `0`.**

Of course I can do the enum mapping myself and have it produce the correct result:

```rb
> ApiKey.where(owner_type: 'User', api_version: ApiKey.api_versions['v3']).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"api_keys\".* FROM \"api_keys\" WHERE \"api_keys\".\"owner_type\" = 'User' AND \"api_keys\".\"api_version\" = 1"
```

**Is this a bug in ActiveRecord or does it not support enum lookups in this way?** I imagine it would since the whole point of enums is to be able to use a friendly/human readable name.

Thanks!

## Notes

- The `ApiKey#api_version` column is of type `integer`
- I'm using Postgres 9.5
- I'm using `activerecord-4.2.11.1`

## Tracing the Behavior

Here's what's happening in the ActiveRecord source:

- In [`ActiveRecord::Relation#to_sql()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L550) it calls `connection.quote(..)` for each bind value (in this case `User`, and `v3`)
- In [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Quoting#quote()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L14) it calls `type_cast_for_database()` to typecast the `Integer` column
- In [`ActiveRecord::Type::Integer#type_cast_for_database()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/integer.rb#L21) it calls `type_cast()` to do the actual type-casting
- In [`ActiveRecord::Type::Value#type_cast()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/value.rb#L98) it calls `cast_value()` to do the integer-specific type-casting
- In [`ActiveRecord::Type::Integer#type_cast_for_database()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/integer.rb#L39) it calls `value.to_i` to transform `"v3"` (string) into `0` (integer)

Comment: have you tried with `:v3` instead of `'v3'`? the examples on the doc uses symbols https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html I think you have to define `{ 'v1' => -1, 'v2' => ... }` as strings if you want to use strings

Comment: Using `:v3` has a similar issue. It hits the same line -`value.to_i rescue nil` - which returns `nil` and renders as `NULL` in the compiled query.

Comment: Also defining them as `String` keys doesn't help either, unfortunately. Still the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework looks up the column type in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/connection.rb#L14 and then calls serialize via the `EnumType`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L142

If you change your code from a string to a symbol (like it is written in your enum definition), it should work.

On a different note, it might be a good idea to not use numeric enum values as they're problematic to maintain: the data is only readable with the specific version of the application that inserted the record.
As you're using Postgres already, think about using proper enum types. There are good libraries like [pg_enum](https://github.com/alassek/activerecord-pg_enum/) and [torque](https://github.com/crashtech/torque-postgresql) to support this endeavour.

Comment: Thanks - I tried defining it with string keys (`enum api_version: { 'v1' => -1, 'v2' => 0, 'v3' => 1 }`) but still no luck. My best guess is that I'm using `v4.2` which doesn't seem to have that `serialize()` method (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb).

Comment: Ah, found the commit that added the functionality to translate enums via `serialize()`. It doesn't seem available in my version (v4.2.11.1) - https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/67c1719012506c3387df067961252b5df50a97ce#diff-abb244a8c26afeef0165452650430244

Comment: To add to this and make the referencing of the enum more dynamic you should use this version of your query `ApiKey.where(owner_type: 'User', api_version: ApiKey.api_versions[:v3])`. This will ensure that you don't have to worry about the position of the enum changing